# Error in reading objects from jQuery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, arrayobject

I am trying to create an array and add data to the beginning of it. Then with a for loop I print out all the data.
However, it prints an error, as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`.

```js
var coords=new Array();

coords.unshift({tite:"sadsad asdds",artist:"Tik Taak"});
coords.unshift({title:"Heyyy sd",artist:"shahram"});
coords.unshift({title:"brahhh",artist:"Daniel"});


for(var i = 0; i <= coords.length; i++){
 console.log(coords[i].title + " - " + coords[i].artist);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see one of the items is printed as `undefined`. And I think thats the point the error is triggered.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Omitting the fact, that you had a *typo* in your first object (`title != tite`) - change `<=` to `<` inside the `for` loop, else it will return `undefined` error, because it looks for the element on index `3`, which actually doesn't exist.

```js
var coords = new Array();

coords.unshift({title:"sadsad asdds",artist:"Tik Taak"});
coords.unshift({title:"Heyyy sd",artist:"shahram"});
coords.unshift({title:"brahhh",artist:"Daniel"});

for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
  console.log(coords[i].title + " - " + coords[i].artist);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your first array object, title is misspelled.

Comment: Also the `for` has to be `i < coords.length`otherwise it will go to index 3 and cause yet another error.